# What does the OSGi Framework do with the Host bundle when attaching a newly-deployed Fragment bundle?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I have a fragment bundle with a component that has an `@Activate`-annotated `activate` method. I can't find any *definite* information on whether this *should* or *should not* work.

On the one hand, it probably *should* work, in the sense that the Framework attaches a fragment to the host, then restarts the host. The component's `activate` method would then fire up, since it's now part of the host, which activates once more.

On the other hand, it probably *should not* work, since the Framework *would not* restart the host when attaching the fragment. In which case, the `activate` method never fires.

I tried tinkering with my bundle on my own, and it seems to *not work*, but I'm not sure if this is because of the latter case I mentioned above, or because of something else. I tried looking at the [documentation](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.fragmenthost), and there's no mention of how the Framework handles the lifecycle of a fragment and host during attachment, beyond the fact that the fragment gets resolved.

My question, then, is what does the OSGi Framework do with the host when attaching a newly-deployed fragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declarative Services does not support the `Service-Component` header in fragment manifests. So while the classes of a component and the XML component description for a component can come from a fragment, any `Service-Component` header in a fragment's manifest is not processed.

See https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.component.html#d0e38069.